# How can I find the value of a matrix that minimize a least square cost function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, vector, minimization

Given the value of S1 which is a vector of size (1,K), I want to find the value of matrix B of size (N,M) that can minimize the following least square cost function:

```
sum(S2 - S1).^2
```

Subject to:

```
S2(i)>=S1(i) \forall i \in {1, .., K}
```

Where S2 is a vector of size (1,K) and is a function of matrix B.
S2 can be calculated after optimizing matrix B using the following system parameters and equations:

```
clc;
clear;

% Given system parameters:
N = 2;
K = 4;
M = 2;
C_l = 4;
H = [0.1185    0.2811; 0.3550    0.8224; 0.3260    0.9644; 0.5333    0.6083]; % 4*2 matrix
A = [-2 1; -1 1]; % 2*2 matrix
C = [7 -3; 7 -3; -2 1; -2 1]; % 4*2 matrix
P = [25000000   0; 0  25000000]; % 4*4 matrix
S1 = [3.1683    3.1686    1.8716    1.8898]; % 1*4 vector
S2 = zeros(1,K); % intial value
B = zeros(N,M); % intial value

% How can we optimize the value of the B matrix to achieve our goal? 

%calculate S2 from B and the other given inputs
for j=1:1:N
    d(j) = (B(j,:)*P*B(j,:)')/((2^(2*C_l))-(norm(A(:,j))^2));
end
D_d = diag(d);

for i=1:1:K   
    V_d(i)=C(i,:)*P*B'*H(i,:)'*inv(1+H(i,:)*(A'*D_d*A+B*P*B')*H(i,:)');
    sigma_d(i)=norm((V_d(i)*H(i,:)*B-C(i,:))*(P^(1/2)))^2+(V_d(i)^2)*(1+H(i,:)*A'*D_d*A*H(i,:)');
    
    S2(i)=0.5*log2((P(1,1))/sigma_d(:,i));   
end
```

Comment: This is very irritating: Which variable do you want to optimize? `B`? `S2`? And at which point in your code you want to do this? (what is all the other fuzz?) You may want to read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Anyway, the good thing is: MATLAB can handle optimization with *inequality constraints*, e.g. [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html)

Comment: I need to find the optimal matrix B that makes minimize the difference between S2 and S1 vectors
As shown in the given equations S2 is a function of matrix B

Comment: I see. If you need this formulation, where you don't restrict the optimizing value (the flattend `B`-matrix in your case), you will need to work with nonlinear constraints. Have a look at [`fmincon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html). You need to formulate two functions: the cost function and a function which calculates `S1` and `S2` from `B` and which output a single `true`/`false` if your desired constraint holds